# Devcomponents SuperGridControl CellButtonClick event

Tags: c#

I am using the Devcomponents `SuperGridControl` and it works well; However I want to fire an event when the button in the cell is clicked. I have tried the CellClick event but it only fires when the cell itself is clicked (the free space) but if a button is clicked there is nothing happens and I can't find a Cell Content Click event or something like that...

Note: I have no code to provide because it is obvious how that I override the CellClick event.